# Programmatically detect if wp-cron is disabled?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron

I have a plugin that relies on WP-Cron to carry out background tasks. I want to warn the user the plugin will not work when it is disabled.

Is it possible within a plugin to programmatically check if WP-Cron has been disabled?

Comment: Site Health Status already does it, but it is prone to false positives (at least in my experience). Have you tried simply scheduling an event for +x mins and checking if it was executed?

Comment: Note that I disable WP Cron so that I can trigger it via WP CLI using a system command. Turning off wp-cron in `wp-config.php` doesn't mean that no wp cron jobs run

Answer (score 1):

First, I would check the constant 'DISABLE_WP_CRON'. If that constant is true, I would already warn the user.

Then I would set a cron job with your plugin to update an option in the database. That option should be updated only by the cron job of your plugin.
Then you can check if that option is updated.
If that option was updated, then the cron system is working.
If it's not updated, you can warn the user by asking to check if the cron is enabled.